# Cmake parse parameters into code

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

Can I parse a parameter out of a configuration file in `cmake` and paste this as a parameter into the `C++` code?

I need to dynamically set the template value `N` for `std::array<T,N>` that depends on some system properties?

`N = (a - b) / c`

Where all should be system parameters.

Comment: /OT _@El Dude_ **HEY!!**

Comment: Are these system properties available in CMake?

Comment: Pass a preprocessor macro definition to the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass preprocessor macro definitions to the c++ compiler using the `-D` compiler flag:

```
MY_CALCULATED_ARRAY_SIZE = "(a - b) / c"
CXX_FLAGS = $(CXX_FLAGS) -DN=$(MY_CALCULATED_ARRAY_SIZE)
```

Comment: Can I automate reading `a,b,c` from a specified file with cmake?

Comment: @ElDude Include some other `CMakeLists.txt` formatted file that contains the definitions.

Comment: @ElDude Let's have a "white russian" together ;-). There's plenty of ways you could go with CMake to realize what you want to achieve. Actually your question comes up _too-broad_ regarding this. Finally it boils down, how you pass `N` downwards to your c++ code, and `-D` in `CXX_FLAGS` is the way to go. The rest is covered in the CMake documentation.